# How to reduce IPC time for Barnes-Hut N-Body coded in C++ and MPI in Parallel Implementation

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, ipc

To simulate N-body problem with Barnes-Hut Algorithm for parallel implementation, how can I reduce the inter-process communication (IPC) time to build an efficient code?

Currently for my C++ and MPI implementation, the more processors/cores are used, the more inter-process communication times are used, which slows down the parallel implementation execution time considerably.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow, @Martin You may already know, the StackOveflow Community has adopted a so called MCVE-formatted problem definition. Feel free to re-read the Community practices and review / update your post, so as to meet this Best Practice. ( + Being at university, your professors would not like to see a graph, with an axis-legend, where a 2.5-body problem seems to be promoted as an expectable experimental setup ... better review the graphing, so as to stay within the domain of physical reality **`:o)`** )

Comment: @uers3666197 Thanks for you comment. What is wrong with my graph? Sorry, I don't fully understand.

Comment: Welcome, @Martin, in the first round, I did not see the `x1E4`, which appeared in front of my eyes just now. Mea Culpa ...  Yet, the scaling ought be right in the Axis-text - like "**Number of Bodies [1] x 1E4**". Next, the computing time is almost for sure not linear in between of your few discrete number of experiments, that were indeed run - if for no other reason, due to principally stepwise adverse effects of scaling, growing cache-line miss effects et al. So it should be the "plot" of the experiments, not a plot-of-extrapolated ( yet, false ) presented per-partes linear-model, shan't it?

Comment: Last bud not least, would you mind to also post the actual code-execution platform's NUMA-topology details? At least the **`lscpu` +** hwloc / **`lstopo` outputs?**

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Maybe I should rephrase my questions as follows:

Comment: I can think about two methods. 1. First, one processor holds all the information of bodies for the entire system, builds a quadtree using that information, and then distributes subtrees to all other processors. Then each processor calculates the forces on bodies using the subtree it received. How would you distribute the quadtrees while keeping in mind load balancing issues? If the subtree that processor A receives is a subtree of processor B's subtree, what do you do so that forces between bodies aren't considered more than once? Is this an efficient method of parallelizing the algorithm?

Comment: 2. Each processor receives a certain number of bodies, and builds its own quadtree using those bodies. Then, one after the other, each processor will send out its own bodies to all other processors, and have the processors calculate the forces on its own bodies. Afterwards, the information will be gathered back at the original processor that sent out the bodies. One main problem is that collisions are not detected if two bodies are on different processors.

Comment: Is there any way to detect collisions without checking every body against every processor's bodies? Also, would this method yield correct results (forces/positions of the bodies)? This is my current implementation.
3. Any other better methods?

Answer (score 0):

> *can I **reduce** the inter-process communication (IPC) **time to build an efficient code ?***

### Short answer: <sub>yes, yet it will not make the code as better as if 've optimised any other part(s)</sub>

For better clarity of this conclusion, let's add a bit more details, for which let's re-use a Barnes-Hut algorithm run-time analysis, as was published from TU Delft :

> <sub>the Barnes-Hut tree is traversed by sending messages to access remote parts of the hash table. There are many standard techniques to lower the communication needed, including overlapping communication and computation, prefetching parts of the tree, processing tree nodes in the order they become available rather in the order they appear in the tree, and caching.
>
>   
>
>   Here are some performance results of an astrophysics calculation taken from literature, again on a 512 processor Intel Delta. 8.8 million particles are involved in the simulation, which are initially uniformly distributed. The time for one Barnes-Hut step is 114 seconds, or 5.8 Gflops. The breakdown of the time is</sub>
>
> ```
>    Decomposing the domain           7 seconds
>    Building the tree                7 seconds
>    Tree traversal                  33 seconds
>    Communication during traversal   6 seconds <------- 6 / 114 ~ < 5 %
>    Force evaluation                54 seconds
>    Load Imbalance                   7 seconds
>    Total                          114 seconds
> ```
>
> <sub>Thus, the floating point work of force evaluation takes almost half the time, so the implementation is reasonably efficient. At later stages of the calculation, the particles become highly clustered, and the time increases to 160 seconds, but with about the same timing breakdown as above.</sub>

---

Having seen this, there are 95 % of time, that take ~ 108 seconds per iteration, which have much higher chances to shave-off some part of the run-time, than the IPC, which keeps the N-body algoritm "together" right "across"-the-footprint of the distributed computing infrastructure.

A relative improvement of a 100 % faster IPC block ( involving a non-existent or a not-available today IPC-technology tricks ) will save **no more than ~ 3 seconds** off the bill ( yet, at unknown add-on side-effect costs ).

A relative improvement of a 10 % faster non-IPC processing block, on the contrary, will bring one **~ 10.6 seconds off the bill**, with a zero add-on side-effect costs, even with some slight improvement on the IPC-implementation ( drivers, stack, et al ) part.

This is more a question of a professional **management of realistic costs/benefits** ( and side-effects ) than an algorithmisation issue.

Comment: Do you have the link to the paper or source code? Thanks.